# Can the outer most layer of a black hole be composed of magnetically trapped photons?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, photons, quantum-optics, gravitational-lensing

The way neutron star's surface is mostly electrons could a black hole surface be mostly photons? Would it bend light similar they way this plastic wrap bends light around the tomato?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean "hidden"? How is the tomato supposed to be "hidden"? Again, [**write a proper question title**](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6413/50583) and *please* show more effort when asking questions.

Comment: @ACuriousMind fixed them trying to be creative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since black holes are invisible bodies in the space (they're so dense that even light can not escape) they can't be mentioned as "hidden". also if the photon sphere you're talking about is close enough, it's most likely to be absorbed by the extreme gravity of the black hole.